# How to ensure multiple forms inputs are valid before going to onSubmit?

Tags: reactjs

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = React.useState<number[]>(arr1);

  const submitAll = (allInputs) => {
    
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {arr.map((num) => {
        return (
          <form key={num}>
            <input type="text" required />
          </form>
        );
      })}

    <button>submit</button>

    </div>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hq55uc?file=App.tsx

When I click submit all 8 forms input should be valid. In the example above, they each should have 1 value. How to do this? I'm open to any alternative way. In my main app I have an array of X items, and I want to create a form for each item (for example, im deleting a transaction given multiple transaction Ids, but I want to have an input that says why I deleted this transaction for each transaction).

Comment: Why are you using 8 separate forms while 1 would be enough?

Comment: How ? The number of form will be random, so I could have 1-20 separate inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can iterate over all the required inputs, you can simply pass a validation function to the input's `onChange` listener.

Additionally, as @DINK74 stated, using multiple `form` elements seems a little redundant when just one would suffice. However, if this is just a result of the simplified code: feel free to revert it to your original layout.

```
export default function App(){
    const arr = useMemo(() => arr1, [arr1]);
    const inputValues = useRef({});

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        const { current: values } = inputValues;
        // Do something with values data...
    };

    const validateInput = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        // Do some validation...
        if(validationPassed){
            inputValues.current[name] = value;
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                {arr.map(num => (
                    <input name={num} onChange={validateInput} required key={num} />
                ));
                <button type="submit">submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This works even better - thanks!